# For each element in a N dim numpy array, add it to a 1D numpy array and return a N+1 dim array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to add each element of a numpy array in turn to another numpy 1D array, but not as an element-wise operation.
More specifically, define `func`:

```
import numpy as np

array1 = np.array([1,2,3,4])
array2 = np.array([10,20,30])

def func(array1,array2):
  #what goes here?
  return output_array

output_array = func(array1,array2)
```

So that:
`output_array = np.array([[11,12,13,14],[21,22,23,24],[31,32,33,34]])`

I have managed to make it work using:

```
def func(array1,array2):
  return np.array(list(map(lambda x: x + array1,array2)))
```

However, it seems like there should be a much better way to do this, and it would also be useful to generalise this to n-dimensions.  I have had a try with `np.vectorize()`:

```
def func(array1,array2):
  np_function = np.vectorize(lambda x: x + array1)
  return np_function(array2)
```

But this does not work as it tries to assign a sequence to a single array element inside the iterator (error "setting an array element with a sequence").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a special function or anything, this is a text book use case for numpy's [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) functionality. All you need is:

```
output_array = array1[None, :] + array2[:, None]  # or even array1 + array2[:, None]
```

To understand it take a look at the differences between

```
print(array1.shape)          # (4,)
print(array1[:, None].shape) # (4, 1)
print(array1[None, :].shape) # (1, 4)
```

When you broadcast a `(4, 1)` with a `(1, 4)` you get a `(4, 4)`

Comment: This is what I was looking for - would this method support N-dims without the specific indexing inside [ ]?

Comment: nD solution: `def outer_add(*arrays): return reduce(np.add.outer, arrays)`

Comment: Unfortunately can't add that as an answer thanks to the dupe-hammer-happy 10k user up there >.>

Comment: @DanielF `np.add.outer` works just fine for n-dim arrays as well, does it not? You can always draw the attention of the voter with tagging, if there are doubts on voting.

Comment: @Divakar I thought @toomuchrock wanted multiple 1d inputs -> nd output.  But yeah, `np.add.outer` works for nd inputs as well.

Comment: @DanielF I see the mention of multiple/n-dimensions, not multiple 1D arrays. Hope I didn't miss it somewhere. Let me know if I did.

Comment: @Divakar  I thought that last `func` was an attempt to make a recursive function.  But it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 1):

Another way: np.add(array2.reshape(3,1), array1)

Comment: ...but I like the simplicity of Dan's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just reshape your first array to 2d then add it to second array.

```
array3 = np.reshape(array2,(-1, 1))+ array1
```

Output :

```
[[11 12 13 14]
 [21 22 23 24]
 [31 32 33 34]]
```